# What is so special about Rewarded Video Ads?

Tags: android, ios, admob, unity-game-engine, chartboost

In addition to Banner ads and Interstitial ads, Admob provides a kind of ads called the Rewarded Video Ads. What is so special about Rewarded Video Ads? Can't we just attach an AdOpen event handler to an ordinary Banner or Interstitial Video ad, and reward the players there? Is this allowed by Google?

Additionally, why is the status of my Chartboost source 'pending' in Admob mediation? I have already set up my account, ads and the campaign in Chartboost, and waited for 6 hours. How long do I have to wait? Must I install the Chartboost SDK first in Unity 5.3?

Answer (score 3):

Rewarded video is special because, on average, it has a higher ecpm (effective cost per mill impressions).

In basic terms:

As a **publisher** (showing ADs in your games), they will make you more money and cost you less uninstalls and bad reviews.

The user chooses to watch the video, so they are not annoyed by an involuntary popup. They also get a reward at the end, so it is a positive experience. This means they are less likely to have negative feelings towards your game, leading to less uninstalls and less bad reviews.

As an **advertiser** they will get you higher quality installs in a cost effective manner.

This is due mainly to the fact that people seeing the AD and installing it know much more about the game than they would from a static image, and therefore you get users that are less likely to uninstall the game due to misleading images or wrong expectations.

You should build a separate process for rewarded video, follow the guide lines here:[Google Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ZxbVL60cHFo)

And see here for Chartboost instructions: [Chartboost Documentation](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/209756523-Mediation-AdMob)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @turnipinrut about rew vid’s strongpoints. I’d also add that rew vids can be implemented in a greater number of ways, depending on game and it’s mechanics. You can show video ads as a random bonus, give free lives/coins/diamonds for ad view especially if you have a «game store» or just show skippable videos after several levels/tries. Playing around with ad frequency is also important, but it mostly depends on the avg game session, amount of tries gamer usually does and audience at all. To sum up, vids are good and can generate decent revenue & keep users loyal if you chose the right placement.

Answer (score 0):

Rewarded Videos are some kind of quest for users :)

### How to add:

In your **onCreate** add

```
Chartboost.setDelegate(CBDelegateObject);
```

and after that

```
private ChartboostDelegate CBDelegateObject = new ChartboostDelegate() {
        // Declare delegate methods here, see CBSample project for examples
        @Override
        public void didCompleteRewardedVideo(String location, int reward){
            //give a reward
        }
};
```

Happy coding ;)